# Looking for Distro With easy OpenCL support

Tags: opencl

I am looking for a distro with OpenCl support that is **not** Ubuntu or Fedora. I am open to any other distro I didnt have any luck in linux mint cinnamon.

I am running an 5700XT.

Comment: A random example is PCLinuxOS-2021. `lib64opencl-devel` is version 2.2.14 . .... You can try out a live-DVD : Comes with propitiatory AMD (and Nvidia) drivers included. ... (And "synaptic for rpm".)

Comment: ok ty. i am trying arch rn because i got told it has opencl in its packet manager.